# MS Access, ComboBox value into SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

The function of my form is to allow a user to assign another user a task, this works fine. The user selects who they want to assign a task to via combo box which is linked to an access DB, I am now trying to implement  a feature were by I can get the value of that selected user from the combobox (by matching the ID in the combox to the ID in the DB and then finding the email from that row, so I can then insert it into an outlook email message that pops up on when the user clicks "Assign" (the outlook code works fine it is just not pulling a value from the combo box, so on click it brings outlook new email up, but the "To" field is empty, I have also tried to print the variable I am assigning to that field to ensure it isnt an issue with the outlook code and it stills returns no value).

Here is the section of code that wont work....

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailSubject As String
Dim EmailSendTo As String
Dim MailBody As String
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim s As String
Dim sqlStatement As String

Combo2.SetFocus

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblUsers.Email FROM tblUsers WHERE tblUsers.UserID = 'Combo2.Text ")
```

Combo2 is the name of the combobox

Comment: Is this VBA, VB6, or VB.NET? Those are not the same things, and neither are BASIC. Please clarify.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Basic 6.5, sorry I don't use this apart from recently for work so completely forgot about different versions.

Answer (score 0):

May be so?

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblUsers.Email FROM tblUsers WHERE tblUsers.UserID = " & Combo2.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

Comment: Then `& Combo2.SelectedItem.ToString()` or without `.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

If your UserID is `Text` try this one:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblUsers.Email FROM tblUsers WHERE tblUsers.UserID = '" & Combo2.Text & "'")
```

However, if your UserID is `numeric` try this one:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblUsers.Email FROM tblUsers WHERE tblUsers.UserID = " & Combo2.Text)
```

Comment: The first one doesn't bring up an error but it is still not picking up any value and the second gets an operator error

Comment: @Josh Did you reference `rs` after you set `rs`? For example like this one: `Email = rs("Email")`

Comment: yeah now I am getting no current record, but I have checked the DB several times so don't get it

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand how Access comes into play, so if this is wrong I apologize.  This is how I would do it in Access:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailSubject As String
Dim EmailSendTo As String
Dim MailBody As String
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim EmailTo as String
Dim s As String
Dim sqlStatement As String

Combo2.SetFocus

Set db = CurrentDb
EmailTo = DLookup ("Email", "tblUsers", "tblUsers.UserID = '" & Combo2.Text & "'")
```

If your UserID is an INT, you would change that last line to:

```
EmailTo = DLookup ("Email", "tblUsers", "tblUsers.UserID = " & Combo2.Text & "")
```

By the way, you said Edper's solution "didn't pick up anything".  You know that "rs" isn't going to have an actual value in that scenario, right?  rs("Email") would, however, so if you added:

```
EmailSendTo = rs("Email")
```

after his SQL string, that MIGHT give you what you needed.

Comment: Now saying no current record through edgars way, which makes no sense as I have checked the DB several times to ensure no errors...

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code.  You can do that simply by clicking in the left margin next to a line of code.  A red circle will appear, this is your breakpoint.  Run the code.  When it gets to the breakpoint, you can now step through your code line-by-line.  Do this, and check each variable as you get to it to make sure your code is resolving your variables correctly.  This is where I usually discover that what I think a variable should be equal to is not what Access thinks the variable should be equal to.  For example, you might need to pull Combo2.Value instead of Combo2.Text.